# How to implement a tag1+tag2+... search using only SQL

Tags: mysql

I have an objects, tags, and tag_relationships table. Objects and tags each have an id column, and tag_relationships connects the two.

Sample of tag_relationships (used in example below):

```
+--------+--------+
| obj_id | tag_id |
+--------+--------+
| 1      | 1      |
| 1      | 2      |
| 2      | 1      |
| 2      | 3      |
| 2      | 4      |
+--------+--------+
```

I want to implement an AND search to allow people to filter tags. Only obj_ids that have a row with the all of the given tag_ids should be returned. For example:

**Sample input: 1, 3** (would actually be tag names, but they would converted to ids)

**Desired output: 2**

It feels like this should be easy, but for the life of me I can't figure out a simple way to do this. I'm currently thinking of returning a table with all the rows in tag_relationships that have one of the given tag_ids, then sorting through them with PHP. Is there a simpler, SQL-only method?

Comment: It's almost like this problem has been solved [many times] before... two naive approaches that readily lend themselves to this are: `COUNT(... WHERE x IN (1,3)) = 2` (or a derived table instead of `IN`) and `JOIN (as many times as needed) WHERE t1.x = 1 AND t2.x = 3`.

Comment: That being said, the at least 3 different "pre-done" approaches to solving this in MySQL (not necessarily with just that table format) with their pros and cons...

Comment: Unnecessarily rude, but your solution worked! Thanks pst!

Comment: I didn't mean to be rude, apologies if it came off as such :) Just things like this are "solved problems"; it's not that they can't be [re]derived, but using an existing solution take advantage of existing work done (e.g. how does it scale?). Glad you got something working.

Comment: If I was a more efficient searcher, I probably would've found one. But I agree entirely with your viewpoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `HAVING` clause in conjunction with `GROUP BY` to answer questions involving *all* of something...

```
SELECT
    obj_id
FROM
    tag_relationships
WHERE
    tag_id IN (1,3)
GROUP BY
    obj_id
HAVING
    COUNT(*) = 2
```

The `2` in the `COUNT(*)` represents the number of tags you are searching on. If you wanted objects that satisfied say, three tags... (e.g. `1,3,6`), you would up the `COUNT(*)` to `3`.

Comment: Yep. This is perfect! Thanks Zane